# Camera adaptative live streaming

Tags: camera, raspicam, ffmpeg

I would like to stream my Pi 2 camera content to web browsers, with player hosted on the same pi.

I have built libav with hardware encoding, and nginx with rtmp module.

Everything seams to work : video streaming is well done, producing rtmp readable by a flash player.

I would like to go steps further : use http and not rtmp, with adaptative video bitrate. So I configured DASH and HLS in the nginx rtmp module.

Files seams to be generated, but video does not seam to work.

I publish the video stream with the following commandline :

`raspivid -n -mm matrix -w 1280 -h 720 -fps 25 -g 100 -t 0 -b 5000000 -o - | avconv -c:v h264_mmal -i - -c:v h264_omx -an -f flv -rtmp_live live rtmp://localhost/picam/picam`

Does someone has managed to do dash or hls live streaming with adaptative bitrate ?

Next question is does someone know a good free player that can play hls/dash videos, preferably without flash, but with eventualy a flash fallback, even to RTMP ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want flash and want something modern for the Raspberry Pi with adaptive audio/video streaming to web browser in the fastest possible way (< 150ms), the only solution is [UV4L](https://www.linux-projects.org), which works out-of-the-box (just install and use). You can set the min, start, max bitrate as options in the configuration file. For it to be played in the same Raspberry Pi you will need a browser supporting WebRTC running on it (e.g. Firefox).